# Static global variable vs function static variable C language

Tags: c, variables, scope, global-variables

my first question here.
can anyone explain to me the differnce between a global static variable (that is, defined above the functions and the "main" combined with "static") and a static variable that is defined inside a function?
as i understand it, they do the same - both enlarge the variable scope to the whole file, and both restrict it to the specific file. so... what am i missing?

plus another question (that came up when looking for a solution) - what is extern? i thought that defining a variable above the main would make it global (as in to other files too), but then i read someone explaining that in order to do so, i must add "extern" before the varible defining.

Comment: Please read [Storage-class specifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration)

Comment: i guess you answered the second part of my question. thanks, that helped alot

Answer (score 0):

For variables defined outside of a function, the `static` keyword limits the variable to being referenced using its identifier from the file in which it is defined.  Variables of this type will be assigned a fixed address by the linker (outside of the heap and stack), but will not be assigned a global symbol.  If variables of this type are defined in multiple files with the same identifier, the linker should allocate separate memory in each case and should compile without warnings.

Variables defined with the `static` keyword inside of a function have similar memory allocation, but references to the variable using its identifier are limited to within that function.  You could have multiple functions defining `static` variables with the same identifier and each will be allocated separately.

If an initializer is used for `static` variables, the variable is initialized once before the program begins executed and the initializer is evaluated at compile time.  The initializer must evaluate to a constant expression in this case (no function calls or parameter or variable references).

The compiler will typically build each C file independent of all of the others in a program using symbols to define external dependencies, such as variables and functions located in other files.  After each source file is compiled, the linker processes the compiler output to replace symbols with fixed addresses and build the entire program.  In order to properly execute the build, the compiler must know the types and sizes of all external functions and variables.  The type and number of parameters and return type of functions are typically shared in a header file using function prototype declarations.  Function prototype declarations are implicitly identified as external by the compiler.  The `extern` keyword is used to specify the type and size of variables declared in files outside of the file referencing the variable.  Declaring a variable without the `external` keyword would cause it to be defined within the module where it is declared.  If two variables with the same identifier are declared in multiple files without the `static` keyword, then the compiler will typically generate an error since the same global symbol is used multiple times in the program.

Comment: `static` affects linkage, not scope. Every object has a fixed address during its lifetime; this is not particular to those of static storage duration. C does not have global variables; neither external linkage nor file scope is fully global. The initializer for a static object does not need to be a literal; it can be any constant expression.